# How to find index of a substring in a SpannableString

Tags: android, spannable, spannablestringbuilder

I have a spannable string and I want to find the index of a substring in the spannable string, I don't want to convert it back to a string as the spannable string is already formatted.

Comment: You trying to find the index of Spanned substring or any substring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextUtils` has many variations [of `indexOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#indexOf(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) to find the index of `CharSequence` in another `CharSequence`. Both `String` and `SpannedString` are `CharSequence` implementations.